Appium Studio - Error while creating .def file
Appium Studio Version: 23.8.9159
I am trying to follow https://docs.digital.ai/bundle/TDB/page/as_-_generate_device_enablement_file_def_using_xdef.html
and I'm using this command to create a .def file, but I'm encountering the error below:
./xdef def -appleId abc@gmail.com -password appspecificpassword -teamId myteamId -devicesPath /Users/myusername/devicefile.txt -p12Pwd 123456 -v
The command generates a .p12 file, but afterward, the following error occurs, can someone assist what is worng here:
15:31:04.748 [main] ERROR c.e.d.i.p.d.DevPortalController - The devices already found at the accountabc@gmail.com:NX6DFDSS creating provisioning profile without adding devices
15:31:04.749 [main] INFO c.e.d.i.p.d.cli.commands.Command - Finished Creating Def file
– Error: Failed to create Def file
Error: operation failed.
Empty password
15:31:04.754 [main] WARN c.e.d.i.p.d.cli.commands.PrintOuts - Exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty password
at profile.devportal.accounts.ProcessP12File.(ProcessP12File.java:34)
at profile.devportal.accounts.AppleAccountInfo.hasValidCert(AppleAccountInfo.java:105)
at profile.devportal.accounts.AppleAccountInfo.hasValidCert(AppleAccountInfo.java:130)
at profile.devportal.clients.PortalClient.downloadprofile(PortalClient.java:251)
at com.experitest.device.ios.profile.devportal.DevPortalController.createProfileInner(DevPortalController.java:331)
at com.experitest.device.ios.profile.devportal.DevPortalController.getProfile(DevPortalController.java:323)
at com.experitest.device.ios.profile.devportal.cli.commands.DefCommand.act(DefCommand.java:98)
at com.experitest.device.ios.profile.devportal.cli.commands.Command.performCommand(Command.java:121)
at com.experitest.device.ios.profile.devportal.cli.commands.Cli.main(Cli.java:29)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:84)
at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.start(UnixLauncher.java:69)
at install4j.com.experitest.device.ios.profile.devportal.cli.commands.Cli.main(Unknown Source)
